# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ents'

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I need your help to solve the problem below. I am applying nlp steps (stops words, tokenization, ner...) on my **french text** (look at the variable txt). I'm using Spacy library.
I receive this error when i want to test the **return_NER** method :
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "NLP_treat.py", line 47, in <module>
ner = test.return_NER(stemmers)
File "NLP_treat.py", line 35, in return_NER
Nerr = [(X.text, X.label_) for X in ste.ents]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ents'
```

Here is my code :

```
import spacy
import json
nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_sm")
import string
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer(language='french')


class NLP:
def __init__(self, text = None):
    self._text = None
    if text:
        self._text = text 

def tokenize(self, text):
    text = "".join([char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation]).lower()
    tokens = word_tokenize(text)
    return tokens

def rem_stopwords(self, list):
    stopword = set(stopwords.words('french'))
    stopW = [word for word in list if word not in stopword]
    return stopW

def return_stem(self, stopW):
    stems = [stemmer.stem(X) for X in stopW]
    ste = " ".join(stems)
    return ste

def return_NER(self, ste):
    # Retourner le texte et le label pour chaque entité
    Nerr = [(X.text, X.label_) for X in ste.ents]
    return Nerr 


txt = "...L’implémentation d’une stratégie expérimentale des projets Machine Learning. 
L’implémentation d’une structure de validation de la qualité des données.La rédaction de rapports 
portant sur la qualité des données en provenance des différentes sources. La refonte de la Pipeline « 
Apprentissage des modèles de Machine Learning. Automatisation des scripts d’évaluation des modèles 
selon les critères définis par les unités Business L’automatisation de la phase d’apprentissage des 
modèles. L’implémentation de la technique « Stacked Ensemble ». La mise en place d’un modèle de 
détection d’anomalies « Isolation Forest ». L’intégration de la détection d’anomalie suivant la 
technique semi-supervised-learning. Déploiements des 3 micro-services à travers différentes images 
Docker. Restructuration du pipeline de l’apprentissage des modèles prédictifs. La réalisation d’un 
POC servant à prédire le volume des produits retournés. La mise en production du POC en question."

test = NLP(text = txt)

tokens = test.tokenize(txt) #réfléchir à enlever les guillemets

print(tokens)

y = test.rem_stopwords(tokens)

print(y)

stemmers = test.return_stem(y)

print(stemmers)


ner = test.return_NER(stemmers)

print(ner)
```

Comment: remove the `.ents` ? what are you expecting that part of your code to do?

Comment: The **join()** method of **string** in python returns a string. This type has no attribute **ents**, which you are calling. You're looping on a string.

Comment: `stemmers` in your case are supposed to be of `Doc` class, i.e. `nlp(text)`, whereas you pass it as a string. Remedy it and you'll be fine to go.

Comment: When i remove .ents, i get this error : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: This is because you keep using a string like it is a token created by the SpaCy library. You have to change your code in order to work, for example by removing **ste = " ".join(stems)**